# Как решить проблему логической репликации PostgreSQL 10

Tags: postgresql, репликация

Имеется сервер master с таблицей subscribers. В этой таблице PK является поле msisdn bigint без сиквенса, определяется при insert скриптом, формирующим SQL запрос.

Периодически в логах ошибка
`ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "subscriber_pkey"`

Я в таком случае просто удаляю запись в slave с тем же PK. Но периодически проблема появляется снова. Я попробовал сделать триггер на INSERT в slave, который проверяет наличие записи в slave и удаляет ее перед INSERT.
Далее, для триггера выполнил ENABLE REPLICA, но он не отрабатывает. Ошибка продолжается.

Какие могут быть причины неуникальных записей при логической репликации и как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Выяснилось, что delete все-таки происходит на master, а потом insert с тем же PK. Решилось добавлением реплики на delete.